# What's the difference between [], @each, content, and <arrayName> in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, properties

I've looked around but I cannot find any good documentation on what the actual differences are between the following:

```js
Ember.Object.extend({
  // ...
  myProperty1: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray'),
  myProperty2: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray.content'),
  myProperty3: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray.[]'),
  myProperty4: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray.@each')
});
```

I do understand that `.content` seems to be the internal storage of the array for the property, which may not be available if this happens to be a `PromiseArray`. I also understand that `@each` would not be used in this fashion, but mostly to access to a `ProxyArray` that generates results as a result of mapping the internal properties of each of the elements in this array.

Besides those subtle differences, they seem to work pretty much the same. But what about `myArray` and `myArray.[]`? And what  about them in constrast with the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ember.Object.extend({
  // ...

  // Updates if myArray is set to a new value using .set
  myProperty1: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray'),

  // Updates if myArray is an Ember Object (like an ArrayController)
  // and its 'content' property is set to a new value using
  // .set('content', newArray) or .replaceContent(...)
  // which can also happen implicitly
  // Also note that for an ArrayController 'content' is an alias of 'model'
  myProperty2: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray.content'),

  // Updates if myArray is an Ember Array or ArrayProxy or MutableEnumerable
  // and it is 'mutated' using myArray.addObject(s), myArray.removeObject,
  // myArray.popObject, myArray.shiftObject, myArray.pushObject(s), etc.
  myProperty3: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray.[]'),

  // Updates if myArray is an Ember Array or ArrayProxy and one of it's
  // elements is set to a new value using .set or .replace
  // such as this.set('myArray.firstObject', 10) or
  // this.get('myArray').replace(2, 1, [10]);
  myProperty4: function() { /* ... */ }.property('myArray.@each')
});
```

I'll also note that if you forget to use one of Ember's methods and simply update the array using simple JavaScript like this:

```
this.myArray = [];
```

none of these computed properties will be updated.

Comment: Impressive answer. Straight to the point and clear. Thank you very much.